# Autoclose Macro in a PDF

Tags: pdf, macros, acrobat

For testing purposes I am trying to create a PDF that, upon opening, automatically closes itself and closes Acrobat Reader. Similar to having an Auto_Open macro in Word that executes: Application.Quit.

I have Acrobat Professional 9.0 but I cannot see how to do that. However, I see discussions of "Actions" (Acrobat Macros) on the Acrobat website.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actions are not quite what you are looking for…

And Acrobat/Reader can not completely do what you are asking it for… For security reasons, it is not possible to programmatically terminate Acrobat/Reader. So, Quitting is not possible; all you can do is closing the document.

You would use Acrobat JavaScript for that. In order to see that it really works, I suggest to first try out a two-page document. To the second page, you add the following PageOpen script (later on, you can do that with the first page too):

```
this.dirty = false ;
this.closeDoc() ;
```

You create a PageOpen script by displaying the page tumbnails, and then select the context menu of the page you want to access. There you open the Page Properties… dialog, and switch to the Page Actions tab. Select Run a JavaScript as action for PageOpen, and add the code above.

Update, after comment by Neil Weicher :

If you want to delay the closing, you could use the `setTimeOut()` method, as showing in this example (which also uses the argument for closing the document without asking whether to save (the equivalent of setting the dirty flag to false); the delay is 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds)):

```
myDelay = app.setTimeOut("this.closeDoc(true) ; app.clearTimeOut(myDelay) ;" , 5000) ;
```

Note: although the timeout object should get reset when the document closes, it is safer to do it in the delayed script.

And that should do it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. the command appears to be _this.closeDoc()_ rather than this.close. Interestingly it appears to shut down Acrobat.exe but not AcroRd32.exe. I wonder why that is? One thing I am trying to add to it is a 5 second delay before executing closeDoc.  I tried adding this before the closeDoc, but it seems to ignore it:
    _this.timeDelay = 5;_

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake about closeDoc; I corrected it in the answer. I also added the correct code for a delay. (timeDelay is not Acrobat JavaScript).

Comment: I found a menu action File.Exit. I added a separate question for it as it seems a slightly different subject.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29470866/cannot-execute-file-exit-action-in-acrobat-pdf

Comment: Thanks again. There was a opening paren missing. I think you meant this?
`myDelay = app.setTimeOut(("this.closeDoc(true) ; app.clearTimeOut(myDelay) ;" ), 5000) ;`

Comment: GRRRR… Thanks again for your feedback. In fact, the closing parenthesis before the comma is not needed. I corrected my answer again, and copy/pasted the code from my test document, which worked…