# Cannot Execute File.Exit Action in Acrobat PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, macros, action, acrobat

Using Acrobat Professional 9.0 I added a Page Open action to Execute Menu Item: *File->Exit*.

However, when I open the page I get the popup: "This action cannot be performed".

I tried enabling all security checkboxes in Preferences I could find with no luck, including:
*Enable menu items Javascript Execution privileges*

Any idea how to run this Menu Item?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This menu item can no longer be executed for security reasons.

Comment: Is there any way to set security settings in a PDF to allow it? Is there any way to shell to a CMD?

Comment: To explain my answer: this means, "not from the document". Of course, you can do it from an external application, such as via Applescript on Mac.

Comment: If the menu item no longer works, it begs the question why Adobe has it in there. In any case - I am trying to automate some testing. I am trying to have a CMD file open the PDF and then after a few seconds have the PDF close itself and close Acrobat. Can you think of a way of doing that?

Comment: With Applescript, I could stitch something together quite quickly…